# Removing css class of the <img> tag after loading it

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I have this code

```
out.print("<img class=\"blurry-load\"  style=\"margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;left:0px;top:0px;\" id=\"" + getId() + "\" " + 
              " onmousedown=\"registraPosicion(event);\"   ondragstart=\"registraPosicion(event);\" ondrag=\"reposiciona(event);\" ondragend='setTimeout(\"registraPosFinal();\",500);\" 'onload='loaded((this.id).removeClass(\"blurry-load\"));'" + 
              "src=\"" + request.getContextPath() + "/imagestore/" + newFileName + 
              "?" + getNode() + "=" + selectId + "&" + "image.index" + "=" + fileIndex + "\" width=\"" + widthSize + 
              "\" height=\"" + heightSize + "\" alt=\"Tamaño " + widthSize + " x " + heightSize + "\">");
```

i need that the img css class that only purpose is to blur the image while loading (blurry-load), get removed from that image after being loaded to make this work i need to figure out:

1.- How i can remove the (class="blurry-load") effect from the img tag

2.- i tried with ('onload='loaded((this.id).removeClass("blurry-load"));'"), in the above code but the image stills blured after being loaded.

3.- About the awfull format of the img tag, its bc this tag is sent from a java method in jsp.

What i am doing wrong? thanks in advice

Sorry for my poor choice of words.

Edit: Both solutions worked so fine, i selected the one who actually needs less code. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you can add an onload attribute (in an editor) you can remove a class attribute so I guess you haven’t just added onload to this element but are needing to use JavaScript so please show us a minimal but complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what `loaded` does but if you try `onload="this.classList.remove('blurry-load')"`, it should remove the class.

```css
.blurry-load {
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<img
  class="blurry-load"
  src="https://source.unsplash.com/random"
  onload="this.classList.remove('blurry-load')"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check Browser dev-tools error and set some HTTP header in your server;

Suppose your **loaded((this.id).removeClass("blurry-load"));** can  works well.
While I have used

```
onload='this.classList.remove(\"blurry-load\")'
```

instead.

```
var dom = "<img class=\"blurry-load\"  style=\"margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;left:0px;top:0px;\" id=\"123\" " +
    " onmousedown=\"registraPosicion(event);\"   ondragstart=\"registraPosicion(event);\" ondrag=\"reposiciona(event);\" ondragend='setTimeout(\"registraPosFinal();\",500);\" ' onload='this.classList.remove(\"blurry-load\")'" +
    "src=\"https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png\">"
    ;
  document.body.innerHTML = dom;
```

I tried to invoke my code in [Chrome search page,](https://www.google.com/search?q=hooks) and I get an error below.

```
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'nonce-PxTqxbqt1d1UAo7im3idcw' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.
```

[image]
It's because of Google HTTP header is setted to

```
content-security-policy: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-PxTqxbqt1d1UAo7im3idcw' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/cdt1
```

[unsafe_hashes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#unsafe_hashes) is not included in this;